# List all GitHub repos for an organization - INCLUDING those in teams

Tags: github, github-api

Here's my query to the GitHub API

```
curl -i -u {user} https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos?type=all
```

But this does not list all repos for this organization that I have access to. Specifically, it does not list repos in the organization that are part of a team that I am a member of.

If I were to query

```
curl -i -u {user} https://api.github.com/teams/{teamid}/repos
```

I would see the missing repos. If I were to navigate to github.com, I would see both private organization repos and my team repos next to each other on the same page. Is there a way to get all of these repos in the same API query?

Answer (score 49):

You can use the below command

```bash
gh repo list {organization-name}
```

before this login with below command

```bash
gh auth login
```

github.com/cli/cli

Comment: `gh` is the new GitHub CLI: https://github.com/cli/cli

Comment: Yes, Boris is correct. I missed this comment.

Comment: `gh repo list {organization-name}` does not show all repositories: 
`Showing 30 of 65 repositories in @linksplatform that match your search`

Comment: Yes by default it shows only 30 repos. if you need more repo then you can use -L flag.


gh repo list {organization-name} -L 100

Answer (score 8):

I apologize. It was listing all my repos...on subsequent pages. Learning about "page=" and "per_page=" was all I needed, and now I can see all of the repos I need.

Comment: Its a shame that there is no end point to get the total count of repos under a particular org. I kinda hacked using `per_page=500` so cover most cases.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories

Comment: per_page=100 is the max value.

Comment: https://api.github.com/orgs/btcgpu/repos?type=all&per_page=100&page=1

Answer (score 4):

To add to original answer, below command can be used if there are many repositories and you wanted to fetch required number of repos. Without `-L` flag it returns 30 items by default.

```
gh repo list <org> -L <#>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have `gh`, the github cli (https://cli.github.com/) and `jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)  you can do this:

```
gh repo list $ORG -L $COUNT --json name | jq '.[].name' | tr -d '"'
```

where $ORG is your organization name and $COUNT is the max number of repos returned

Answer (score 3):

Download the official gh cli, the github cli (https://cli.github.com/)

```
gh repo list $ORG -L $COUNT --json name --jq '.[].name'
```

Set $ORG equal to your organization name, and $COUNT to be the amount of Repos you want to list. (Set $COUNT equal to the amount of repos in the organization if you want to list them all)

Answer (score 0):

curl -i -u "username":"password" https://your_git_url.com/organization_name | grep "codeRepository" | awk -F '"' '{print $6}'

Comment: This just counted repositories. Wasn't the question for a list of all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the "per_page"-attribute to "0"? I have seen some APIs using a default value of for example 20, but if you activately set it to 0, like `?per_page=0` you get all pages.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, didn't work unfortunately.